# How should I connect a new light fixture with black, white, blue and green wires?

Tags: wiring, light, install

I have a halogen bathroom fixture with two halogen bulbs. I have one black wire and one white wire from the wall. A dimmer switch activates this fixture, and an overhead can light simultaneously. The fixture I want to install has the following: two white wires, two black wires, a blue wire, and a green wire. The manufacturer tied one pair of the white and black wires in a loose knot. 1. Should I change the dimmer switch to a simple on-off switch? 2. How do I install this fixture safely? I am a mid-level DIYer.

Answer (score 1):

Some light fixtures don't connect the blacks and whites to a single wire for you, so they'd connect to the supply wires with matching color. Use good technique with whatever connectors you've chosen so all conductors are secure.

The green wire is ground. It'll connect to the bare ground from your supply cable, and possibly to the junction box, depending on whether it's metal.

The blue wire strikes me as a night light or something else, but I'm taking wild guesses since I don't know what fixture we're discussing. If that's the case you'd either add it to the black bundle or connect it to a separate switched or constant hot wire.

Whether you need to eliminate the dimmer depends on whether the lights are dimmable and whether the dimmer is compatible. Dimmable halogens don't tend to require specifically-compatible dimmers like LEDs often do, but again, I don't know what hardware you have in front of you.